# GridviewRowCommand not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a gridview, which each row have a edit and a delete button.
I've managed to put my edit button working, but not the delete button.
Here's my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvfaq" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="faq_id" OnRowDataBound="gvfaq_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvfaq_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="gvfaq_RowDeleting" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="text" HeaderText="Text" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="editbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("faq_id") %>' CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="delbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("faq_id") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
protected void gvfaq_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        DeleteFAQ(ID);
    }
}

protected void gvfaq_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button l1 = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("editbutton");
        l1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Javascript:suport(" + l1.CommandArgument.ToString() + ");return false;");
        l1.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", "Javascript:suport(" + l1.CommandArgument.ToString() + ");return false;");
        Button l2 = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("delbutton");
        l2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')");
        l2.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')");
    }
}

protected void gvfaq_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)this.FindControl("gvfaq");
    int ID = (int)gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
    DeleteFAQ(ID);
}

protected void DeleteFAQ(int ID)
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand())
    using (SqlConnection myServerCreate = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServerCreate"].ConnectionString))
    {
        myServerCreate.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = myServerCreate;
        myCommand.CommandText = "delete from faq where faq_id = " + ID;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Close", "__doPostBack('','Delete');", true);
}
```

The strange, is that I have another page, from where I copied/rearragend this code, and there is working fine.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
If I check the html generated on the other page button, this code is added, which doesn't succeed in this:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$gvDocuments$ctl02$delbutton", "", true, "", "", false, false))
```

Comment: I can see you are binding the commandname to different name `CommandName="Eliminar"` and checking against `Delete`

Comment: sorry, I've changed the language for better understanding, in the code, all references are correct.

Comment: ok i dont see that.is the rowcommand gets fired in debug ?also why are you checking against "delete" when your command name is something else

Comment: How can I check if it is fired?

Comment: set breakpoint on rowcommand and debug and hit delete button.does breakpoint hit ?

Comment: No, it doesn't break. Could it be because of the javascript alert?

Comment: sorry have no idea what is happening there.Please try to create a minimal,verfiable example.Your question does not at all reflect the actual problem